# ASP.Net C#: Call serverside function together with Jquery BlockUI

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, blockui, jquery-blockui

I want to show a Jquery blockUI when I click an asp:button that triggers a serverside function.
When the function ends, I want to do the unBlockUI.

Is this possible? If so, can I have an example, cause I'm not an Ajax specialist.
Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encosia has an excellent sample at http://encosia.com/2008/10/04/using-jquery-to-enhance-aspnet-ajax-progress-indication/ that describes how to do this using an UpdatePanel.

You can find a sample using jQuery ajax, ASP.NET and blockUI here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=391